# Со временем замедляется requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript, html, css

Простой черновик движения и коллизии на JavaScript.
Вначале игры все работает нормально, но спустя секунд 30-40 движения становятся резкими и медленными.
Что не так?

```js
const canvasjs = document.getElementById('canvo');
const ctx = canvasjs.getContext('2d');
const sizeOfCell = 40;
let frames = 0;

const player = {
  x: sizeOfCell * 5,
  y: sizeOfCell * 7,
  width: sizeOfCell * 5,
  height: sizeOfCell * 7,
  draw() {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  },
  move() {
    let objectTemporary = {};
    for (let key in player) {
      objectTemporary[key] = player[key];

    }

    if (buttons.w) {
      objectTemporary.y -= 10;
    }
    if (buttons.a) {
      objectTemporary.x -= 10;
    }
    if (buttons.s) {
      objectTemporary.y += 10;
    }
    if (buttons.d) {
      objectTemporary.x += 10;
    }
    if (collision(objectTemporary, block) != true) {
      player.x = objectTemporary.x;
      player.y = objectTemporary.y
    }
  }
}
const block = {
  x: sizeOfCell * 10,
  y: sizeOfCell * 10,
  width: sizeOfCell * 2,
  height: sizeOfCell * 2,
  draw() {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}
const buttons = {
  w: false,
  s: false,
  a: false,
  d: false,
  mouse: false
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  switch (event.code) {
    case 'KeyW':
      {
        buttons.w = true;
        break;
      }
    case 'KeyA':
      {
        buttons.a = true;
        break;
      }
    case 'KeyS':
      {
        buttons.s = true;
        break;
      }
    case 'KeyD':
      {
        buttons.d = true;
        break;
      }
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  switch (event.code) {
    case 'KeyW':
      {
        buttons.w = false;
        break;
      }
    case 'KeyA':
      {
        buttons.a = false;
        break;
      }
    case 'KeyS':
      {
        buttons.s = false;
        break;
      }
    case 'KeyD':
      {
        buttons.d = false;
        break;
      }
  }
});


function collision(first, second) {
  if (((first.x > second.x && first.x < second.x + second.width) ||
      (first.x + first.width > second.x && first.x < second.x + second.width)) &&
    ((first.y > second.y && first.y < second.y + second.height) ||
      (first.y + first.height > second.y && first.y < second.y + second.height))) {
    return true;
  }
}


function drawMap() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 800; i += sizeOfCell) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, i);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasjs.width, i);
    ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(i, canvasjs.width);
  }

}

function update() {
  player.move();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasjs.width, canvasjs.height);
  drawMap();

  player.draw();
  block.draw();


  ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray';
  ctx.stroke();
}


function game() {

  let isKeyPressed = false;
  frames++;
  if (frames >= 60) {
    frames = 0;
  }
  for (let key in buttons) {
    if (buttons[key] == true) isKeyPressed = true;
  }
  if (isKeyPressed == true) {
    update();
    draw();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(game);
};
game();
draw();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#canvo {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="game.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvo" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы забываете сбросить очередь рисования через `ctx.beginPath()` и в итоге `ctx.stroke()` рисует сотни и тысячи копий сетки, и чем больше копий накопилось, тем больше тормозит

Comment: Спасибо, помогли